# React-Table: exception thrown calling 'getResolvedState()' on component ref

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref, react-table

I am trying to implement the download feature using React Table, the `react-csv` package, and TypeScript.

I am trying to create and use a reference for the table component using `createRef()` however it is throwing the following exception

> "Property 'getResolvedState' does not exist on type 'RefObject'" error.

My code is as follows:

```
import {CSVLink} from "react-csv";
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';

export default class Download extends React.Component<{},{}> {

  private reactTable: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  constructor(props:any){
    super(props);
    this.state={} // some state object with data for table
    this.download = this.download.bind(this);
    this.reactTable = React.createRef();
  }

   download(event: any)
   {
    const records =this.reactTable.getResolvedState().sortedData; //ERROR saying getResolved state does not exist
     //Download logic
   }

    render()
    {
       return(
       <React.Fragment>
       <button onClick={this.download}>Download</button>
       <ReactTable 
           data={data} //data object
           columns={columns}  //column config object
           ref={this.reactTable}
       />
     </React.Fragment>
    }
}

Any help would be appreciated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find that the issue is resolved by:

1. revising the way you relate the `reactTable` ref to your `<ReactTable />` component [as documented here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs), and
2. accessing `getResolvedState()` from the `current` field of your reactTable ref

Also, consider wrapping both of your rendered elements [with a fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to ensure correct rendering behavior:

```
/* Note that the reference type should not be HTMLInputElement */
private reactTable: React.RefObject<any>;

constructor(props:any){
  super(props);
  this.state={};
  this.download = this.download.bind(this);
  this.reactTable = React.createRef();
}

download(event: any)
{
   /* Access the current field of your reactTable ref */
   const reactTable = this.reactTable.current;

   /* Access sortedData from getResolvedState() */
   const records = reactTable.getResolvedState().sortedData;

   // shortedData should be in records
}

render()
{
   /* Ensure these are correctly defined */
   const columns = ...;
   const data = ...;

   /* Enclose both elements in fragment, and pass reactTable ref directly */
   return <React.Fragment>
   <button onClick={this.download}>Download</button>
   <ReactTable 
       data={data}
       columns={columns}
       ref={ this.reactTable } />
   </React.Fragment>
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! Now its throwing   " Object is possibly null! Property 'getResolvedState' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'. "

Comment: Great - glad I could help :-)

Comment: Would you be able to post this question in a new post please? and send me the link? it's a bit hard to understand the your problem in the comments area :-)